# If the electric field inside a conductor is zero, why is the potential must be continuous?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I was wondering by myself while solving some electrostatics problems, if I have a conducting sphere (for example) that has charge only on its boundary, why do I need to demand that the electric potential is continuous at the boundary, instead of just gauge it to zero inside the sphere.

Eventually, we are interested in the electric field, not in the potential, and I can still gauge it to zero and get the same result.

Comment: Demand what? It comes out that way. And no, the potential is not zero inside it is constant inside. It's the field that is 0 inside.

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar Everything you said I already know. I am asking why., we are intresting in the electric field. zero potential will give exactly the same electric field as constant potential

Comment: Because 0 potential inside the sphere has physical implications which are wrong. By definition, you take potential to be 0 at infinity, and saying that potential is 0 inside is the same as saying no work would be done bringing a charge from inf to inside, which means the field **outside** is also zero, which is wrong.

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar Ohhh that's excatly what was missing to me. thank you for clraify that for me. you can write it as an answer and I will mark it as a solution so it will help other ppl in the future. thank you again!

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar "by definition, you take potential to be 0 at infinity" -- no, you don't. By (one common) *convention*, you take the electrostatic potential to be zero at infinity. It is always possible to gauge away from this convention, as OP proposes to do, which obviously breaks that convention. There is nothing wrong with doing that, so long as you are careful not to mix-and-match conventions, which is what your second sentence ("saying that potential is 0 inside is the same as saying no work would be done bringing a charge from inf to inside") is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I need to demand that the electric potential is continuous at the boundary, instead of just gauge it to zero inside the sphere.

- You *need* to demand that the electric potential be continuous at the boundary, because the physics requires it.
- You *can*, if you want to, demand that the electric potential be zero at the surface, if you find it to be convenient.

On the other hand, if you choose a gauge where the potential is zero at the surface, you're liable (read: guaranteed) to lose the convenient properties of whatever gauge you started with. When dealing with isolated, finite systems, we normally choose a gauge where the potential is zero at infinity (and indeed if you're not working within this convention you need to make that *very* clear and explicit). If you re-gauge it to be zero at the surface, then the potential will be nonzero at infinity, and all the work that you previously had to put into calculating the potential at the surface will now go into calculating the potential at infinity.

All things told, the gauge choice as regards the electrostatic (scalar) potential has an essentially negligible impact on the complexity of calculations. The story is different in magnetostatics, where the right choice of gauge can make a calculation significantly simpler (obviously without affecting the physics), but in electrostatics this really isn't the case.

Comment: I think, based on the comments, that the OP had already assumed potential to be $0$ at infinity and was asking about setting potential to be 0 inside the sphere since its absolute value doesn't matter. Your answer is spot on, but I think he is asking in some other context.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field inside a non-driven conductor must be zero. If it were not zero, it would cause the free electrons to shift position until it was zero. For two points to have a different potential, there must be an electric field between the points.  If there is no field inside a conductor, then any two points inside or at the surface must be at the same potential.

Comment: I agree, but is this is wrong to gauge the potential inside it to zero?

Comment: The potential inside an isolated charged conducting sphere will be the same as at the surface, which is not zero.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but my reasoning is that :
While moving a test charge +q from just outside the sphere to just inside it, the work done by the system(Charged Sphere) is

Force × displacement

And here displacement is very very small(almost 0) and force is finite(as force is same as a point charge at center which is finite even at boundry condition) and hence work done in this process is (almost) 0. And
hence change in potential is 0(it is continuous while moving from outside to inside).